# Uniform continuity of $f(x) = \frac {1} {x^3}$ on $(0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Not sure about the Uniform continuity of $f(x) = \frac {1} {x^3}$   on $(0,1]$. Unsure where to begin. My textbook showed that $\frac {1}{x^2}$ was not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.

Edit: Looking for hints to show that $f$ is not in fact uniformly continuous on this interval using familiar theorems.

Comment: For small $x$, $f(x)$ is growing very fast. So it is natural to guess that $f$ is not uniform continuous.

Comment: Hint: a uniformly continuous function on a dense set can be continuously extended to the completion of that set. Can your function be continuously extended to $[0,1]$?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @avs asking for hints about how to determine whether $f$  is or isn't uniformly continuous on the described set.

Comment: @ArcticChar I'd agree,but that's not a proof or counterexample. The interval isn't bounded, so since f is continuous on (0,1], this doesn't garuntess it's uniformly continuous.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I would say not since any sequence $1/x^3$ converges to positive infinity for smaller and smaller $x \in (0,1]$

Comment: @James Dickens: right! Now try either to prove my claim, or just use your insight and work directly from the definition.

Comment: Of course that's not a proof. You don't know where to start, so my comment is meant to be providing some intuition.

Comment: @symplectomorphic answer attempt given with last part missing.

Comment: @JamesDickens, uniform continuity can be ``pictured'' as follows.  One is asking the following.  Let a positive $\epsilon$ be given.  Does there exist a rectangular box of height $2\epsilon$ such that every point in the graph of $f$ can be enclosed by this box with the graph passing through the vertical sides of the box (and not passing through the top or bottom of the box).  Can be found for every $\epsilon$, the function is uniformly continuous.

So, the first step I recommend is trying to experiment graphically with your $f(x)$ and to find such boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not uniformly continuous by contradiction. Suppose that I could extend my function to $f'(x)$ such that $f'(0)=r$ for some $r \in \Bbb R$, then for any sequence $x_n$ converging to 0, we have lim $f(x_n) = \infty$, and cannot therefore equal r, thus $f$ cannot be extended to some $f'$ such that $f'$ is continuous on [0,1] and so $f$ is not uniformly continuous on (0,1). Now how does this relate to showing that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on (0,1]. If a function is not uniformly continuous on a subset $A \subset B$ then f is not uniformly continuous on B?